# How to do stop scrolling uitableview if new rows are not there in uitableview in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, c, uitableview, uiscrollview

How to do stop scrolling uitableview if new rows are not there in tableview in objective c?

Comment: you have numberOfRows where you define the number of rows available on the tableView, or you want to disable the bounce?

Comment: i want to disable bounce if new data is not there.

Comment: You can just toggle visibility of TableView according to the data. If no data is available then simply hide the tableview.

Comment: Thank you all for quick response i got solution from my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i got solution from my side     myCartTableCell.attributeTableView.bounces=NO;
its works for me ...

Answer (score 2):

For disabling bounces for the tableView you can use:

```
self.tableView.bounces = NO;
```

this will disable it when it gets to the last row